# Using the command window to convert LaTeX to HTML

Tags: miktex, conversion, windows, tex4ht

I am trying to convert a LaTeX file to HTML. I have tried to do this by typing `cmd` into the search bar of the START menu.  When the black background box comes up, I type in `htlatex filename.tex` where instead of filename I write the name of the file.  It then comes up,

```
I can't find file filename.
Please type another input file name.
```

I am using MiKTeX and Windows 7.

Comment: You need to change to the folder that contains `filename.tex` using `cd the\folder\that\has\the\file`. Under Windows (7), if the folders have spaces in them, you can press `<TAB>` to auto-complete the folder name, or use quotes: `cd "\Document and Settings\Users\XYZ\Documents\LaTeX"`, and then use `htlatex filename.tex`. Regardless, this is off-topic.

Comment: @Werner: I also think it is off-topic but you can provide an answer -- "First steps inside the command window".

Comment: This is your fourth question on TeX.SX and we welcome new questions. However, you have not accepted any answer to any of your questions here and you have neither voted on any of the answers you have gotten. Please see the [faq#howtoask] for details on accepting and voting.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change to the folder containing `filename.tex` before executing `htlatex filename.tex`. Under Windows, this can be achieved using

```
cd path\to\the\folder
```

You can either use backslashes `\` or forward slashes `/`. If your path contains spaces, you can either use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to let Windows auto-complete a partially completed folder name (that is, you type `cd Docu` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and Windows will auto-complete this to `cd "Documents and Settings"`), or use quotes to denote the folder names, for example

```
cd "Documents and Settings\Users\XYZ\Documents\My Documents"
```

Once in the correct folder, use

```
htlatex filename.tex
```